# Equicontinuous sequence in $C(\mathbb{R^2})$ and Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Could anyone help with the following problem?  I am trying to work out this last practice problem for my Real Analysis prelim but I'm not sure about how to approach it.  It looks very similar to the second version of the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem in Folland's Real Analysis text book, but I'm not entirely sure.  Does it use the first version of that theorem?

Suppose that $\{f_n\} \subset C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and there is an $M > 0$ such that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^2} |f_n(x)| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Prove that if $\{f_n\}$ is equi-continuous on each compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ and an $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $f_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ and $n_k \rightarrow \infty$ locally uniformly for $x \in \mathbb{R^2}$.  That is, $f_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ as $n_k \rightarrow \infty$ uniformly in any bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a nice sequence of compact sets $K_N$, let's say the closed ball of radius $N$ centred at $0$, whose union is all of $\mathbb R^2$.  The sequence $f_n$ is equicontinuous and equibounded on $K_1$, so there is 
a subsequence that converges uniformly on $K_1$ to some function $g_1$ continuous on $K_1$.  This subsequence is still equicontinuous and equibounded on $K_2$, so it has a subsequence that converges uniformly 
on $K_2$ to a function $g_2$ on $K_2$.  Note that since we know the subsequence converges to $g_1$ on $K_1$, $g_1$ is the restriction of
$g_2$ to $K_1$.  And so on...  A diagonal sequence that is a subsequence of all the subsequences converges to a continuous function $g$, uniformly on each $K_N$, and thus uniformly on any bounded subset of $\mathbb R^2$.